# how to insert data from datagridview to database mysql vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

here's my code

```
MysqlConn.Open()
            command.Connection = MysqlConn
            command.CommandText = CommandType.Text
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO order VALUES (@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8)"
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", rw.Cells(0).Value)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", rw.Cells(1).Value)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", rw.Cells(2).Value)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", rw.Cells(3).Value)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", Now())
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@6", TextBox6.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@7", TextBox7.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@8", TextBox8.Text)

            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        MsgBox("done")
        MysqlConn.Close()

        command.Parameters.Clear()
```

i already did the "insert into order (`names`, .....) values (@1,....) but still not working. im using mysql

Comment: There is no need to fish data out of a DataGridView if you use a DataSource; that code has an errant `Next` which makes it seem like you are doing this in a loop; that in turn means the code could be wrong.  What does 'not working" mean?  `Dim rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery()` will tell you how many rows were inserted (again with a DataSource and DataAdapter they can all be inserted at once.  PLEASE read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Please fix your code. You should be naming your columns in your insert statement. `Insert into MyTable(Col1,Col2,....) Values (@p1, @p2...)

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins i already did that. but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
       Dim I As Integer
                For I = 0 To Dgrd.Rows.Count - 2
                    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = Dgrd.Rows(I)
                    Dim SQLCON As New SqlConnection(MyDataBaseCon)
                    Dim CMD As SqlCommand
                    Dim S1 As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = row.Cells(1)
                    Dim S2 As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = row.Cells(2)
                    Dim S3 As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = row.Cells(3)
                    CMD = New SqlCommand("Insert Into order 
                   (S1,S2,S3) Values (@S1,@S2,@S3)", SQLCON)
                    SQLCON.Open()
                    CMD.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@S1", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = S1 
                    CMD.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@S2", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = S2
                    CMD.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@S3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)).Value = S3

                   CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
                   SQLCON.Close()

                Next
                MsgBox("done")
```